# Are wavelets for audio spectrograms available as a simple FIR filter?

Tags: fft, filters, wavelet, bandpass, filter-bank

I have read that "*Debauchies Wavelet is simply a short FIR*" so i am searching for a single FIR that i can make into a filterbank, a precise "bandpass filter" that detects narrow frequencies, i.e. 1Hz resolution and very narrow.

Having an FIR filter function allows for multithreading which is not easy with a transformation matrix, and arbitrary analysis windows.

In Reaktor DSP suite i simply used a bandpass to make an amazing filterbank program. I tried the same with a cookbook FIR filter and it was totally erratic and garbled as a filterbank analysis filter, even though it sounds good.

What FIR or wavelet can i use for a filterbank where:

```
 T=time, F=freq;

 for loop T++;                        // (1 second 0-44100 samples)
    for loop F++;                     // (512 bands 0-512 kHz frequencies)
       graph2D[T,F] = FIRfilter(T , F );
```

EDIT- on request, schematic of a bandpass that can be used for audio analysis:
[image]

Comment: Alas, narrow band pass filtering (relative to the sample rate) require long FIR filters, not short ones, especially if you want high stop band attenuation (for which you did not specify a value in your question).

Comment: Thankyou Hotpaw, The following image is what i have previously programmed with a bandpass in Reaktor, i simply want to find a similar filter in code, the resonance was about 0.97, which meant that the filter amplified massively any amplitudes of a particular signal that was detected at precisely the designated frequency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function#/media/File:Winger_ville_vs_FIR_Bank_sonogram.jpg

Comment: Have you measured the bandwidth and stopband attenuation of that filter?

Comment: Hi, i was suprised to find that i had used a Reaktor5 integral "2 pole bandpass", so i have added a shematic of it to the original post, it's made of a "BiQuad I" and a "SetBQPB" element. I had measured the response, it's similar to a perfect guassian bell curve where the apex narrowness is adjustable by change the resonance, used at .95, which creates a trade off between time ant frequency resolution. It's just a perfect bandpass, it's difficult to measure precisely.

Comment: A biquad is an IIR filter.  So you want a FIR filter with a response that approximates a given IIR filter?  There are already other Q&A's here on that.

Comment: Thanks, at first i had read that FIR wavelets were best for filterbanks, i don't understand them and if they are simple i wanted to understand one of them individually, see it's graphs and so forth. So now I have just found that biquad can be used to by revisiting a later version of some work. i'd like to learn about their various particularities, for use in measuring audio bands. it's research in progress.

Comment: Do wavelets have better resolution than IIR as a filterbank? i think the probably do. i don't think there are wavelets available as unit circle filters.